# How to provide plugin for all forms in redux-form?

Tags: forms, reactjs, redux, redux-form

Ok, so I wanted to deal with whitespaces at the beginning of the input in my register form and I have achieved this by providing plugin for redux-form reducer:

```
export default function(cookies, server) {
  return combineReducers({
    auth: auth(cookies, server),
    reduxAsyncConnect,
    alert,
    programs,
    exercises,
    routing: routerReducer,
    form: form.plugin(formPlugin),
    profile,
    spinner,
    companies
  });
}
```

The plugin is:

```
import {ltrim} from './ltrim';

const formPlugin = {
  registerForm: (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
      case '@@redux-form/CHANGE':
        if (action.meta.form === 'registerForm') {
          return {
            ...state,
            values: {
            ...state.values,
            [action.meta.field]: ltrim(action.payload)
            }
          }
        } else {
          return state;
        }
      default:
        return state;
      }
    }
  }

export default formPlugin;
```

How can I get the same effect on all forms withouth hardcoding? Maybe I have to somehow edit redux-form CHANGE action to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a custom `Field` component that does this for you.

```
import { Field } from 'redux-form';
import {ltrim} from './ltrim';

const normalize = value => ltrim(value);

const TrimmedField = props => <Field {...props} normalize={normalize} />;
```

You could also give your custom `normalize` a callback argument if you need to do other normalization in some cases.

http://redux-form.com/6.6.3/docs/api/Field.md/#-normalize-value-previousvalue-allvalues-previousallvalues-nextvalue-optional-